# Writing .txt in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, email, send

In this moment, I'm want to make a very amateur flash game in AS3. I want to make an input field. If someone writes in that, the writing (e-mail address) will be in a .txt next to the file in my ftp server. How can I do this?

Comment: You are creating this online? You have to do it via a server side script. ActionScript alone won't work.

Comment: You need to send the data to a PHP script on your server. Then the PHP will write it somewhere, usually a MySql database.

Comment: Not in the database. The OP wants a text file. But I would suggest PHP too.